# Orbean Server side embedding - CSS issues

Tags: orbeon

We are trying use Orbeon Form runner with server-side embedding.

The form renders properly on form runner, however in our java web application the form is not rendered properly i.e. CSS issues.

All the /orbeon/* resources are retrieved from orbeon application, but the CSS is not applied properly. I suspect it could be because of the extra div that are added for the embedded/portlet.

**In Form Runner**

[image: Form in Form Runner]
[Full Size Image](https://doc-10-5c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/gsbgebhp4a23moh3861olv5ksiaog4t6/tlm80b7rbj9kq37hec12o79su4ntsvmc/1427911200000/09769719400415932844/07548907419783484289/0B2q8pCGmIDmTNXVEV3l0RU5pTnc?e=download)

**In Java Web Application**

[image: Form Embedded in Java Web Application]
[Full Size Image](https://doc-10-5c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/gsbgebhp4a23moh3861olv5ksiaog4t6/1ptf1epkh1pchbigp5ts63nj7eve6no1/1427911200000/09769719400415932844/07548907419783484289/0B2q8pCGmIDmTUGFwbS0ySlNTMU0?e=download&nonce=ut7rch0remd9s&user=07548907419783484289&hash=frb29fem87vqqgivopv1l3fu87fbsv4b)

Also, if we use the wizard view, it works in form runner, but does not work in embedded java web application. The sections are shown on the same screen.

Comment: Please rewrite your question to include the code that is necessary to diagnose the problem instead of posting all your sources as ZIP archives. It's unlikely you'll receive a helpful answer otherwise. Thx

Comment: Hello, there are no zips/code attached, I have just couple of screenshots.

Comment: I see. Could you then edit your question and include the screenshot as part of it using the IMG control? That makes it easier to understand the full problem and your screens will be preserved with the question, otherwise the Q&A may will no longer be useful if you delete the screenshots :-)

Comment: I tried that, but it wouldn't let me add images, it was giving an error message that I need 10 reputations to add images.

Comment: @sascham78 Thank you for inlining the images.

Answer (score 1):

When Orbeon Forms produces the whole page, it adds an `orbeon` class on the `body`, and then pretty much all the CSS that comes with Orbeon Forms is "prefixed" with `.orbeon …`. This is done to minimize the risk of Orbeon Forms' CSS conflicting with your own CSS.

I can't be sure that this is the problem, but if the CSS doesn't apply when embedding, you might need to add a `class="orbeon"` on the element that contains the content you're embedding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your guidance. I was able to resolve the problem.

When [embedding forms](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-APIs-~-Server-side-Embedding), as you said orbeon regenerates the CSS, and also appends "o0" (#o0xforms-form) to each control's id. However, the xforms.css still refers to control with (id #xforms-form), hence styles are not applied correctly.

Overwritten the xforms.css with custom app-xforms.css which uses (#o0xforms-form) which fixes the problem.

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution! Could you add an answer with your solution and accept it? Thx!